# replace commas to columns java jTable

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

I've problem. In my database is column with time of departure.

I need change `,` to create new columns.

I have:

```
-----------------------------
|   col 1            |
-----------------------------
|06:00, 07:00, 08:00  |
-----------------------------
|06:10, 07:10, 08:10  |
-----------------------------

i need:
-----------------------------
| col1  |  col2   |  col3 |
-----------------------------
|06:00 | 07:00 | 08:00|
-----------------------------
|06:10 | 07:10 | 08:10|
-----------------------------


private void UpdateTable(String linia, int poczatkowy){
try{
    String sql = "select liniaId as Nr, (select nazwa from przystanki where przystanki.id=przystankiodjazdy.przystanekId) as przystanek, GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT przystankiodjazdy.godzina order by przystankiodjazdy.godzina SEPARATOR ' | ') as czas from  przystankiodjazdy inner join odjazdy on odjazdy.id=przystankiodjazdy.odjazdId where `liniaId`='"+linia+"' and odjazdy.przystanekPoczatkowy='"+poczatkowy+"' group by przystanek  ORDER BY `czas`;";
    PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet res = pst.executeQuery();
    table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(res));
    TableColumnModel tcm = table.getColumnModel();
    tcm.getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(50);
    tcm.getColumn(1).setMaxWidth(150);

}catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

}

}

Comment: You want to change the database or the `JTable`

Comment: where is the given code excerpt from? Java code? If yes, why not use .replace on the String object?

Comment: I want to change JTable. I want to do more columns

Comment: Do some research into `String#split` and `String#trim`

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).